# Redirect Url on Apache Server

Tags: apache, redirect, http-redirect

I have this url:

`https://pouv.com/presentation/vues/restreint/gestionnaire/****`

I want to redirect to:

`https://pouv.com/bo/`

I do this on my .conf:

```
  ## Rewrite rules
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule https://pouv.com/presentation/vues/restreint/gestionnaire/$ https://pouv.fr/bo/ [R=301,L]
```

the redirection is not done, why ?

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule` directive uses `URL path`   as the first argument . You need to remove the hostname .

```
## Rewrite rules
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/presentation/vues/restreint/gestionnaire/.*$ https://pouv.fr/bo/ [R=301,L]
```

Reference :
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html